# Philosophy of Science and the nature of observation: what counts as 'observable'?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, empiricism, scientific-realism

In the realist-antirealist debate within philosophy of science, the distinction between the 'observable' and 'unobservable' is made very often though I have seen that this distinction is also frequently challenged, some saying that a sharp distinction doesn't exist.

Could someone link me to sources/reading where I can read more about the debate surrounding the observable-unobservable distinction. Arguments about what counts as observable, what counts as unobservable, arguments against the distinction and any of the key thinkers involved in the debates.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [SEP's Scientific Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/), [Theory and Observation in Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/science-theory-observation/), etc.? [Contessa's Constructive Empiricism, Observability, and Three Kinds of Ontological Commitment](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2650/1/Contessa_(forthcoming)_Constructive_Empiricism%2C_Observability_and_Ontological_Commitment.pdf) is a 2006 contribution to the said debate.